# Security Vulnerability in my Java application

Tags: java, security, struts-1

> I am appending the encoded data to the url with the message. Instead
>   of throwing error it is displaying the message appended in the url
>
> my url: https://www.test.com/sa injecting data:
>   https://www.test.com/%2ftest.com%20was%20not%20found.%20Please%20go%20to%20www.hackedurl.com%
>
> On hitting the url the page is displayed asking the user to try
>   www.hackeurl.com instead of application error

Comment: still using struts is almost a guarantee for serious gaping holes, and is itself an indication that you're a decade or more behind the times in other areas as well.

Comment: Agree to the point about falling behind with the tech stack trace used. However, that is not my call alone. Have this problem, any pointers would perhaps help.

Comment: it's hardly ever your call. But without a lot more information it's impossible to say where the vulnerability originates.

Comment: Without context it's impossible to help.